# Reversed and non-reversed list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm getting a byte list into my method. Now I need the byte list reversed and non-reversed. I've tried this:

```
public void Test(List<Byte> dataList)
{
    List<byte> reversedDataList = dataList;
    reversedDataList.Reverse();

    _polls = dataList[0];
    _rpolls = reversedDataList[0]
}
```

The problem is, that both lists are reversed. How can I solve that?

Comment: You're assigning `reversedDataList` a reference to the same object referenced by `dataList`. The two will always be reflective of each other as they refer to the same object in memory. This behaviour is exclusive to reference types and wouldn't have been exhibited with any value types. See: https://www.udemy.com/blog/c-sharp-data-types/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `ToList` after `dataList` to create a copy of your list:

```
List<byte> reversedDataList = dataList.ToList();
```